# getStaticProps vs getServerSideProps for ecoomerce site

Tags: next.js

I'm building an eCommerce website and was wondering which one's better to get for the products page. Products can range from 100-1000. I'm currently using serversideProps but it seems too slow

Answer (score 0):

Considering that an eCommerce website generally has new/changed products, it makes the most sense to use `getServerSideProps`. However, if no new products will be added or no products will be changed, you could use `getStaticProps`.

You could implement a [caching strategy](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching) to speed up the render, such as caching the returned products for a fixed period of time (like 30 minutes).